# Append custom block after addtocart button on the product view page

Tags: magento

I try to do it by custom module xml with this code

> ```
> <catalog_product_view>
>     <reference name="product.info">
>         <block type="custom/myblock" name="myblock" after="addtocart" template="custom/myblock.phtml"/>
>     </reference>    
> </catalog_product_view>
> ```

but it doesn't work. If I change the reference name to content, it goes fine, but I would like to put it after the addtocard button.

How to assign custom block there?

Answer (score 1):

try this its working

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
                    <block type="custom/myblock" name="myblock"  template="custom/myblock.phtml"/>
         </block>
    </reference>    
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: It works, but it looks a bit strange with the <block> statement for product.info.addtocard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, updated block type.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="myblock" after="addtocart" template="custom/myblock.phtml"/>
    </reference>    
</catalog_product_view>
```